# Why is TailWind CSS Toggle not working in localhost?

Tags: html, css, tailwind-css

I have been designing a sidebar for a ToDo page by using Tailwind CSS and in that sidebar, i want a button to toggle between darkmode and lightmode. I copied the code of just Toggling (not switching mode, which I will handle later)  from FlowBite.

Here is the code:

```
<div>
    <aside class='bg-gray-900 w-64 h-screen py-10'>
        <div class='flex items-start justify-start h-10 w-auto py-5 mt-6 cursor-pointer'>
            <CiDark class='ml-8' style={{ color: "white" }} size={32} />
            <span class='ml-3 text-white font-semibold text-xl'>Dark Mode</span>
            <label class='relative inline-flex items-center cursor-pointer'>
                <input type="checkbox" value="" class="sr-only peer" checked />
                <div class="w-11 h-6 bg-gray-200 mt-1 ml-2 rounded-full peer-checked:after:translate-x-full  peer-checked:after:border-white peer:after:content-[''] after:absolute after:top-0.7 after:left-[5px] after:bg-white after:border-gray-300 after:border after:rounded-full after:h-6 after:w-6 after:transition-all peer-checked:bg-blue-600"></div>
            </label>
        </div>
    </aside>
</div>
```

This code works on Tailwind CSS [playground](https://play.tailwindcss.com/T3IJ1ajM0Y) and i am able to toggle. But in localhost, this just won't toggle.

Here is how I have added Tailwind in my react project:

Index.css

```
@tailwind base;
@tailwind components;
@tailwind utilities;
```

Index.js

```
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom/client';
import React from 'react';
import App from './App.js'
import './index.css'

const root = ReactDOM.createRoot(document.getElementById('root'));
root.render(
    <React.StrictMode>
        <App />
    </React.StrictMode>
);
```

tailwind.config.js

```
/** @type {import('tailwindcss').Config} */
module.exports = {
content: [
"./src/**/*.{js,jsx,ts,tsx}",
],
theme: {
extend: {},
},
plugins: [],
}
```

Also rest of Tailwind is working okay. Its only toggle which is not responsive.

Comment: I think you need to include Tailwind in your project correctly. If I add the cdn `<script src="https://cdn.tailwindcss.com"></script>` for testing in my computer it works too.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

React tells you why. Have a look into your console output. You should find something like:

> Warning: You provided a `checked` prop to a form field without an `onChange` handler. This will render a read-only field. If the field should be mutable use `defaultChecked`. Otherwise, set either `onChange` or `readOnly`.

It should work if you change "checked" to "defaultChecked". Not related to your problem, but you should also change all occurences of "class" into "className". class is a reserved word in Javascript.